If one filled in an FBAR in 2021, but in 2022, one no longer has a total of $10,000 in all banks, must one file the FBAR in 2022?
If one filled in an FBAR in 2021, but in 2022, one no longer has a combined total $10,000 in all bank accounts abroad under their name, must one file a FBAR in 2022 and ensuing years if the balance stays under $10k?

No, the requirement for filing FBAR is a combined balance of >$10K on all the accounts at any time during the year.
See here:

Who Must File the FBAR?
A United States person that has a financial interest in or signature authority over foreign financial accounts must file
an FBAR if the aggregate value of the foreign financial accounts exceeds $10,000 at any time during the calendar year.
The full line item instructions are located at FBAR Line Item Instructions. The IRS also has provided a FBAR Guidance
page

However it may be easier to just file it even if not required, than respond to notices and try to find all the statements to prove you didn't have to when asked. See the IRM for the various issues related to examination and record-keeping requirements.
